# Djanga admin custom list_diplay

Tags: django

In the Django admin panel, how do I change admin.py so that each staff can see only their data in the list_display.

For example, there is a news site. 2 staffs will add news to the site. A separate account is opened for each staff. Only the news added by that staff should appear in the list of added news. This is how it is done in list_display? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Override [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) in the ModelAdmin for your model

```
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(added_by=request.user)
```